# Python - How to filter a list by multiples of all elements of a list with a lambda function?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, filter, generator

I have the following code:

```
a = [2, 4]
b = list(range(1,10))
print(list(filter((lambda x: (x % f == 0) for f in a), b)))
```

My goal is to get back:

```
[4, 8]
```

instead I get:

```
TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

This is because between 4 and 8 divide by both 2 and 4. (I'm trying to get my code to work, not solve the specific problem, I know I could just use 4 and solve it quick.) Thank you so much to all!!

Comment: since you are using `list` meaning you are evaluating the `filter` object created, it will rather be good to use list comprehensions ie `[i for i in b if all([i%j==0 for j in a])]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
a = [2, 4]
b = list(range(1,10))
print(list(filter(lambda x: all(x % f == 0 for f in a), b)))
```

Output:

```
[4, 8]
```

The issue is that `(lambda x: (x % f == 0) for f in a)` is a generator, not a function (or `lambda` statement).